# Не работает парсер на питоне (sqlite3.InterfaceError)

Tags: python, парсер, sqlite

Первый раз пишу парсер, опыта нету, как всё работает понимаю плохо, так что прошу помочь, сам вряд-ли решу.

Вот код файла, который создаёт базу данных, в которую по задумке должна помещаться спаршенная инфа.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('mealsdata.sqlite3')

sql = "CREATE TABLE meals (title TEXT, description TEXT, price INT)"
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(sql)

conn.close()
```

И он работает, вроде как :/, по крайней мере файл mealsdata.sqlite3 с таблицей meals он создаёт. Вот основной файл, отвечающий за всё остальное:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3

url = 'https://www.krugly-stol.ru/menu/osnovnoe-menyu/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
title = soup.find_all('div', class_='custom-menu1__tovarlist1_item_info_name')
description = soup.find_all('div', class_='custom-menu1__tovarlist1_item_info_text')
price = soup.find_all('div', class_='custom-menu1__tovarlist1_item_info_price')
args = []
args.append((title, description, price))

conn = sqlite3.connect("mealsdata.sqlite3")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO meals VALUES (?, ?, ?)", args)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Ошибка: sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Ещё, был бы очень благодарен если бы вы подсказали как с того сайта парсить картинки блюд, и добавлять директорию, в которую они сохраняются в БД.

upd. `args = zip(title, description, price)` не помогло, та же ошибка осталась.

Comment: Каждый find_all выдаёт список в результате. Sqlite непонимает, что ему делать с кортежами, каждый элемент которого это список. Можно для начала попробовать так: `args = zip(title, description, price)`, но это если вам повезло и нашлось одинаковое число элементов для каждого списка.

Comment: Насчёт картинок, в бд хранить картинки нельзя, Вы просто загружаете их в какую-нибудь директорию и в бд, сохраняете путь до этих картинок